# Error :RESTORE cannot process database 'Test_DB' because it is in use by this session

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, database-backups

Scenario :

I am working on C# windows form application with SQL Server 2008 R2 database server.all things are going well, even i am able to create data base backup but when i restore it pro-grammatically it give me error **"RESTORE cannot process database 'Test_DB' because it is in use by this session. It is recommended that the master database be used when performing this operation.
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally."** 
here is my program for backup and restore

```
          //   back up code

        try
        {
            SaveFileDialog sd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sd.Filter = "SQL Server database backup files|*.bak";
            sd.Title = "Create Database Backup";


            if (sd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnection"].ConnectionString))
                {

                    string sqlStmt = string.Format("backup database Test_DB to disk='{0}'", sd.FileName);
                    using (SqlCommand bu2 = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt, conn))
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        bu2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();

                        DevComponents.DotNetBar.MessageBoxEx.Show("Backup Created Sucessfully");
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Backup Not Created");
        }
 // Restore backup Code


        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog();
            od.Filter = "SQL Server database Restore files|*.bak";
            od.Title = "Restore Database Backup";


            if (od.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnection"].ConnectionString))
                {
                        string sqlStmt = string.Format("Restore database Test_DB from disk='{0}'", od.FileName);
                        using (SqlCommand bu2 = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt, conn))
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            bu2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            conn.Close();
                            DevComponents.DotNetBar.MessageBoxEx.Show("Database Retored Sucessfully", "Success Message!");
                        }

                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Database didn't Restore","Error Message!");
        }
```

I appreciate any help provided by any body. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory. You need to change your connection string so that instead of `initial catalog=test_db` it says `initial_catalog=master`. Or change the database context to master before running the restore.

Comment: so simple, query where you open connection and try to make restore should be to master database

Answer (score 4):

```
// Restore backup Code


        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog();
            od.Filter = "SQL Server database Restore files|*.bak";
            od.Title = "Restore Database Backup";


            if (od.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnection"].ConnectionString))
                {
                        conn.Open();
                        string UseMaster = "USE master";
                        SqlCommand UseMasterCommand = new SqlCommand(UseMaster, conn);
                        UseMasterCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        string Alter1 = @"ALTER DATABASE [Test_DB] SET Single_User WITH Rollback Immediate";
                        SqlCommand Alter1Cmd = new SqlCommand(Alter1, conn);
                        Alter1Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        string Restore = string.Format("Restore database Test_DB from disk='{0}'", od.FileName);
                        SqlCommand RestoreCmd = new SqlCommand(Restore, conn);
                        RestoreCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        string Alter2 = @"ALTER DATABASE [Test_DB] SET Multi_User";
                        SqlCommand Alter2Cmd = new SqlCommand(Alter2, conn);
                        Alter2Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                           DevComponents.DotNetBar.MessageBoxEx.Show("Database Retored Sucessfully", "Success Message!");

                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Database didn't Restore", "Error Message!");
        }
```